# Count Unique record by Group in MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: This is my database table, i want to count unique number of visits by user, for example alot 5 person visit 5 times, 20 persons visit 7 times etc]

Here is my Query

```
SELECT count(*) as count 
FROM `tbl_track` 
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

Its Result is (1 person visit 2times + 1 person visit 2times + 1 person visit 1time)

```
Count
2
2
1
```

I want a result (2 person visit 2times + 1 person visit 1time)

```
Count
2
1
```

Comment: i need to count total three person visited how this possible

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) as `count`, `visit_times` 
FROM (
  SELECT count(*) as `visit_times` 
  FROM `tbl_track` 
  GROUP BY `user_id`
) AS t GROUP BY `visit_times`
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select cnt as user_count,COUNT(*) as count
from
(
SELECT   COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM tbl_track 
GROUP BY userid)a
group by cnt
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2745d/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VisitsCount
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS VisitsCount
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY UserId
) T
```